# How to map arbitrary requests in SpringBoot?

Tags: spring-boot, request

I need to write a Spring RestController that catches URLs made up by an arbitrary number of variables. Specifically, I need to map something like `/{id1}/{id2}/some/dynamic/path/` alongside "normal" mappings such as `/{someid}` and/or `/`.
`/{id1}/{id2}/some/dynamic/path/` needs to be mapped to three parameters `id1`, `id2`, and `some/dynamic/path`, where the path can be anything from zero to 10 segments.

Maybe I got something wrong, but the `catchAll()` I implemented for this case always catches all - and ignores the other paths. How do I solve this?

Here is my code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyController
{
    @GetMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity staticPath()
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("1", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{someid}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity pathWithOneVar(@PathVariable String someid)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("2", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping("{id1}/{id2}/**")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity catchAll(@PathVariable String id1, @PathVariable String id2)
    {
        HttpServletRequest requestServlet = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        requestServlet.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE));

        return new ResponseEntity<String>("3", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

What I need is:

- Map `/` to staticPath()
- Map `/42` to pathWithOneVar(): var `someid` = 42
- Map `/1/2` to catchAll(): var `id1` = 1, var `id2` = 2, var `path` = ""
- Map `/1/2/a` to catchAll(): var `id1` = 1, var `id2` = 2, var `path` = "a"
- Map `/1/2/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k` to catchAll(): var `id1` = 1, var `id2` = 2, var `path` = "a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k"

Comment: Explain what do you mean by hard coded paths.

Comment: I mean paths which are clearly specified in their format. Such as ```/a/b/c```or ```/myid/{id}```. In my example, specifically ```/```and ```/{someid}```as opposed to the last mapping, which is supposed to map any request that does not fit the other ones.
I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: These three mapping work as expected in Spring Boot 2.1.4 for me